# Object copying in Java

Tags: java

I have a class named as `order` in `package com.abc`
I have another class named as `order` in different package in different project named as `com.bcd`

Both order classes have same code get, set functions and variables with no changes.

Then I have objects

```
com.abc.order obj1 = new com.abc.order();
com.bcd.order obj2 = new com.bdc.order();
```

Now I have to pass arguments to a function and it takes only `obj2` as parameters
How can I convert type of `obj1` into type of `obj2`

I cannot change parameters for the function.

Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

Comment: Can you change your `abc.Order` to extend `bcd.Order`? (Class names should be upper-case, so use `Order` instead of `order` if possible).

Comment: What's the reason for you code? I think there's a something wrong here.

Comment: I have a webservice which gets and sets the details, but a part of them have to be moved to EJB so both will have the same classes.
If all of the code has to be moved to EJB then a lot of changes are required in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Apache Commons BeanUtils to copy properties from one object to another.

http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/index.html

Something like

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(obj2, obj1)
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy each field. You can use a BeanIntrospector to help you do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could overload the function, simply by typing it again in your code, but this time so it will take instances of `com.abc.order` instead. Keep the other one too of course.

If you have defined these two functions, it will work. Problem is duplication. I've never seen a situation like this before and it doesn't sound like good coding practice to duplicate a class and use both in the same code. Can you cast them into each other? like `(obj1) obj2?` I don't think you can but I'm not 100% sure...

Answer (score 0):

The best solution, if you can is to eliminate one of the two classes especially if they are identical.

Otherwise rename them (first letter capitalised, if possible), again if you can.

Finally, if you cannot perform either of the above, write a conversion method on one or both classes, resolve between the classes where used by retaining their package in all usages.

```
import com.abc.order;

abc.order obj1 = new abc.order(); 
bcd.order obj2 = new bdc.order();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make the class **com.bdc.order** subclass of **com.abc.order**

can you clarify why u want to do this ?